# What is a redirect URI and what should it be?

Tags: node.js, redirect, spotify

I am trying to follow this tutorial - https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/quick-start/ to learn how to use the spotify web api. I'm making a simple node.js app as in the tutorial. At one point, the tutorial instructs me to change this information:

```
var client_id = 'CLIENT_ID'; // Your client id
var client_secret = 'CLIENT_SECRET'; // Your secret
var redirect_uri = 'REDIRECT_URI'; // Your redirect uri
```

To my own info. I can find my client_id and the client_secret, but what is my redirect_uri? I know I need to set it in the app setting on spotify for devs but I don't know what to set it to.

Also, the tutorial displays this:

```
var scopes = \'user-read-private user-read-email\'
```

But I can not find that code in the app.js file. Should I just add this or is it necessary? I am very new to using the spotify web api.

Answer (score 1):

Just pulled this from the documentation of Spotify Dev.

In Redirect URIs enter one or more addresses that you want to whitelist with Spotify. This URI enables the Spotify authentication service to automatically re-launch your app every time the user logs in.

This is a common terminology used across most of the developer portals for sort of bringing back the user to your specific app / Website once the user login. Thus the name redirect uri. For development I generally use Ngrok tunnel for redirecting the user back to my dev app and change the Ngrok tunnel with production URL once the entire flow is ready.

[link to the documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/app-settings/)